# Installing a font on a web server for ASP.NET application

Tags: windows-server-2003, web-server, iis-6, font

I've just deployed an ASP.NET application onto a Windows 2003 web server.  The application contains Crystal Reports.  Some of the reports contain characters in WingDings2 font.  When the report is generated those characters show in the standard font instead.

I copied the WingDings2 font to the web server, but it did not help.  I restarted IIS also and that didn't help.

Any ideas?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked again this morning and it now works. I wonder if the server was rebooted over the weekend.

Comment: By experience just copying the fonts to the folder won't help unless it's done using the Fonts control panel applet... so something more than just a file copy is needed - a reboot might trigger a rescan or whatever Windows uses to figure this out?

Comment: That's what I did... I copied the font file into the Fonts control panel.

Answer (score 0):

The report is rendered on the client browser, so unless you're rendering something like a PDF file which can contain embedded fonts, the font needs to be installed on the client computer.

Comment: That not true in this case.  Sorry, should have better clarified.  The Crystal Report is generating a PDF file and making that available for download.

Answer (score 0):

And had you rebooted machine?

IIS does not use the fonts, it is not even used by ASP.NET. I believe that CrystalReports is COM-based.

BTW, which version of ASP.NET, IIS, and CrystalReports we are talking about? Is it CrystalReports for VisualStudio (and which VS?)? or standalone one?

Comment: ASP.NET 3.5, IIS6, CR for .NET.  I checked again this morning and it now works.  I wonder if the server was rebooted over the weekend.

Answer (score -2):

I had the same issue and i solved it installing the Font directly from the server (not through remote desktop)

Comment: ...and then you [pressed the green button twice](http://blog.serverfault.com/2011/06/09/press-the-green-button-twice/)? -- What logic leads you to believe that sitting at the physical console is different than a remote connection in this case?

Comment: @voretaq7 You just killed me - good laugh in a middle of the day is always awsome!